# как передать значение переменной в другую функцию?

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть такая машина состояния. В нее приходит значение, которое хранится в переменной "message".

```
class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup):
    names = State()
    id_tg = State()
    all_game = State()
    winners = State()

async def cm_start(message : types.Message):
    await FSMAdmin.all_game.set()
    await message.answer('Введите количество игр, которое вы сыграли:')
    moon = message.text

async def load_win(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext, moon):
    async with state.proxy() as data: 
        data['names'] = moon
        data['id_tg'] = message.from_user.id
        data['all_game'] = message.text
    await FSMAdmin.next()
    await message.answer('Введите количество побед:')

async def load_lose(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['winners'] = message.text
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        await message.answer(str(data))
    await message.answer("Данные успешно внесены!")
    await state.finish()
```

т.е. я перенес значение переменной message в переменную moon. И это значение moon, мне нужно перенести в другую функцию, в которой это значение должно перейти во временную бд машины состояния. Но на выходе мне выдает: `TypeError: load_win() missing 1 required positional argument: 'moon'`
Как правильно перенести значение moon в следующую функцию?

Comment: Вам не обязательно запускать FSM чтобы использовать хранилище `state.proxy()` просто так же запихните то что вам нужно в стейт

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы предлагаете записать в class FSMAdmin(StatesGroup): в аргумент переменной names, значение которое мне нужно? Если это так, то у меня каждый раз приходят разные значения переменной message. Можете по-подробнее объяснить как правильно добавлять ?

Comment: Нет, просто там где у вас есть значение moon откройте так же стейт прокси и запишите в дату.

Comment: Просто в функцию cm_start добавить: async with state.proxy() as data:  data['names'] = message.text? 
Я так пробовал, и мне выдает ошибку: NameError: name 'state' is not defined

Comment: Ну так добавь аргумент стейта в функцию, в чем проблема?

Comment: так должно выглядеть? async def cm_start(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
Если так, то выдает: TypeError: cm_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'state'

Comment: Где ваши декораторы?